# GUI or HUD for displaying things like battery or ip addresses?

Tags: hud

I would like to know how to display certain information on a HUD on screen at all times, so not in CLI but in small text in the corner of desktop or translucently on top for example.  I must be searching for the wrong terms as I'm getting nothing for 'ubuntu hud display' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky)! It will do exactly as you ask.
The nice thing is there have been loads of people who set up cool conky configs already, so if you're not really into that sort of thing, it's done for you!

[Here](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Configs) are some cool ones to get you started!